# NAMER CNN usability and compatibility problems

Tags: conv-neural-network

I'm trying to use the [NAMER motion-correction CNN](https://github.com/mwhaskell/namer_MRI/tree/main).

It requires tensorflow, keras, Matlab and python of course. However, the author does not specify the versions, and I've been trying everything for 3 days: tf 2.x, tf 1.x CUDA 11, 10 etc., python 3.7, 3.8, and tons of others ... no way to make it work...
can anyone help?

The latest error message I have is:

`2023-12-18 13:48:36.124708: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:319] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.5.0 but source was compiled with: 7.6.0.  CuDNN library major and minor version needs to match or have higher minor version in case of CuDNN 7.0 or later version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.`

But I did download CuDNN 7.6 and copied the files into `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\bin` etc.

I am working on Win 11 + WSL + Matlab R2020a, and lastly python 3.7, tf 1.15, keras 2.2.5.

And what makes it even more complicated is this integration with Matlab. You have to run a Matlab script that calls the python scripts, although Matlab's pyenv should in principle help ( did configure it).

Comment: Windows will use DLL's from the PATH only as a last fallback. There is a 7.5.0 DLL in one of the earlier search locations, likely in the install directory of whatever is supposed to load CUDNN.

Comment: thanks for the comment... this is a nightmare indeed... i can try to search on my disk for another cudnn64_7.dll i guess...